# Error using Avrodeserializer in consumer code - apache kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I am using kafka confluent open source version. I am using avro for serialization and deserialization. My producer java code is able to push the record in broker. But when my java consumer tries to read the data, i get below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordDeserializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition clickRecordsEvents-0 at offset 1. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:1429)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.access$3400(Fetcher.java:134)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1652)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.access$1800(Fetcher.java:1488)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:721)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:672)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1304)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1238)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1211)
    at com.ru.kafka.consumer.deserializer.avro.AvroConsumerDemo.main(AvroConsumerDemo.java:31)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id 1
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:156)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:79)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(KafkaAvroDeserializer.java:55)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:60)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:1420)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Could not find class ClickRecord specified in writer's schema whilst finding reader's schema for a SpecificRecord.
```

I am able to read the records from consumer console command prompt.

Here's my consumer code:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;

public class AvroConsumerDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.put("group.id", "clicksCG");
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer");
        props.put("specific.avro.reader", "true");
        props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8083");

        String topic = "clickRecordsEvents";

        KafkaConsumer<String, ClickRecord> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, ClickRecord>(props);
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topic));

        System.out.println("Reading topic:" + topic);

        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, ClickRecord> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000));

            for (ConsumerRecord<String, ClickRecord> record : records) {
                System.out.println("Current customer name is: " + record.value().getBrowser());
                System.out.println("Session ID read " + record.value().getSessionId());
                System.out.println("Browser read " + record.value().getBrowser());
                System.out.println("Compaign read " + record.value().getCompaign());
                System.out.println("IP read " + record.value().getIp());
                System.out.println("Channel" + record.value().getChannel());
                System.out.println("Refrrer" + record.value().getRefferer());
            }
            consumer.commitSync();
        }
    }

}
```

Note that, I have generated ClickRecord java class using avro schema file and avro tool plugin. Its not plain java pojo.

Here's my producer code:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.RecordMetadata;

import com.ru.kafka.avro.pojo.ClickRecord;

public class AvroProducerDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer");
        props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8083"); // URL points to the schema registry.

        String topic = "clickRecordsEvents";

        Producer<String, ClickRecord> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, ClickRecord>(props);

        ClickRecord clickRecord = new ClickRecord();
        clickRecord.setSessionId("ABC1245");
        clickRecord.setBrowser("Chrome");
        clickRecord.setIp("192.168.32.56");
        clickRecord.setChannel("HomePage");

        System.out.println("Generated clickRecord " + clickRecord.toString());
        ProducerRecord<String, ClickRecord> record = new ProducerRecord<String, ClickRecord>(topic,
                clickRecord.getSessionId().toString(), clickRecord);
        try {
            RecordMetadata metdata = producer.send(record).get();
            System.out.println("Record written to partition" + metdata.partition());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            producer.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your producer code. There's no way to know what deserializer to use without knowing how the producer serialized it. If you use the wrong deserializer, yes, you should expect a similar error. Plus `Could not find class ClickRecord` means your classpath is wrong, so please show your pom or Gradle files

Comment: @OneCricketeer
I have updated question with producer code. Please have a look. Thank you. ClickRecord class is in the same package of produce and consumer as its a demo project

Comment: They're not in the same package, though, since your demo classes show no package statement and your producer demo shows an import for ClickRecord while the consumer code you've uploaded does not